# What the difference between using .NET tasks with method and action?

Tags: c#, .net, action, task

Method:

```
static void HelloWorld() { Console.WriteLine(“Hello, world!”); }
```

What the difference between

```
Task t1 = new Task(HelloWorld);
```

and

```
Task t2 = new Task(new Action(HelloWorld));
```

Comment: In your example, there's no difference. Your `HelloWorld` is an `Action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, actually. In fact, in both cases the compiler generates the same code:

```
Task task2 = new Task(new Action((object) null, __methodptr(HelloWorld)));
```